# Change offset of main while changing width of website

Tags: javascript, html, css

at the top of the site is fixed picture and right bellow it starts main with all of the content. At first I had problems with offset for my main, but I finally figured it out, but now, when I resize my window, it's not changing it's offset until I refresh my page. Is there any way to fix this so whenever I resize my window and I'm at the top of the page, the mains offset height is changing as well as top picture. Here is my CS :

```
#first_image {
        width : 100%;
        min-width: 1100px;
        position: fixed;
        top : 0;
        left : 0;
        z-index: -2;
      }

      main {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        top:;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 100;
        padding-top:25px;
      }
```

JS :

```
var img = document.getElementById('first_image');
var height = img.clientHeight;

$(".maintext").css({ top: height });
```

EDIT: .maintext is class for main.

Comment: Have you tried using $( window ).resize() handler to set offset on resize. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the same code in a `$(window).resize();` event handler. Here's the complete code adding the thing you're doing to resize the image to a function, so that you can call the function by itself when the page loads, and call it when the window is resized.

```
$(function() {
  function imageHeight() {
    var img = document.getElementById('first_image');
    var height = img.clientHeight;
    $(".maintext").css({ top: height });
  }
  $(window).resize(function() {
    imageHeight();
  });
  imageHeight();
});
```

Comment: @AntonioGvardijan sweet! No problem. (oh be sure to mark this as the answer if it solved your issue).